# PHP/Mysql Inserting multiple rows in existing table for csv output

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am creating a table in a specific format from my existing mysql database so I can export it as a csv file to my woocommerce website.

I have no problem creating a row for each product (simple product with no variation), however I am having problems with variable products (requiring several rows each).

The picture below shows an example of 3 products (3 different ParentSKU) in the table

[image: table]

What I need to do is to create a new row for each ParentSKU with the common information of each variation.
i.e. 1 extra row for 14615, 1 extra row for 14622 and 1 extra row for 14624.

I have about 1000 rows that need to be inserted like this.

Below is how I insert my rows in the table in the first place:

```
$Query2 = "INSERT INTO Website ( `ParentSKU`,`SKU`,`Brand`,`ProductName`,`Images`)

SELECT  ID,ID,Brand,Style,MainLink

FROM    StockAccount,Stock_Items

WHERE   StockAccount.ID=Stock_Items.ID_Product AND
    Stock_Items.Name='' AND
    Stock_Items.Returned='' AND
    StockAccount.LAXS='Yes' AND
    StockAccount.MainLink!=''

GROUP BY Size,MainLink

ORDER BY `ID`
";
```

I know how to insert rows one at a time but could not find anything about my particular issue.

Comment: Where do the extensions like `-M` and `-L` come from?

Comment: @RiggsFolly You don't use `VALUES` when you're inserting from a `SELECT`.

Comment: -M and -L come from another column in the same table.

Comment: I update each SKU after they are created with -M, -L...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get a single row for each `ParentSKU`, using the `ParentSKU` also as the `SKU` in the new row.

```
INSERT INTO WebSite (ParentSKU, SKU, Brand, ProductName, Images)
SELECT DISTINCT ParentSKU, ParentSKU, Brand, ProductName, Images
FROM WebSite
```

Comment: No, it doesn't lose anything, it's just inserting new rows.

Comment: Barmar, this is perfect! Than you!

Comment: Is there a way to add a row only if it is a variable product? I mean adding a row for products with serveral variations only.

Comment: ex: if product_type=simple then no extra row. otherwise add an extra row.

Comment: Just add a `WHERE` clause that matches what you want after `FROM WebSite`. So something like `WHERE product_type != 'simple'`